# submitting another form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

Usualy our users use firstname.lastname as username to login to our site. Some of our users who are not located in our domain need to enter a long username (firstname.lastname@aLongDomainName) to be able to use our login form.

Now we have created a simple html file which makes it possible for those users that enter only their firstName.lastName so that jQuery injects the long domain name on the fly and sumbmits the form.

The problem is our real login form contains a generated Token which the fake html form missing it, so the users getting login failed error. How can we get the generated Token? Is there any other solution for the problem?

**Updated:**
Here is the code which is nothing except jquery submit. My question is how can I get a token which generates first when the form is rendered.

```
$("#username").val(uname + "@theLong.SubDomain.Domain.com");

 $("form1").submit();
```

Comment: Post some code first. What have you tried?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the current HTML and javascript.

Comment: We haven't do so much just using jquery.submit() function. the problem is how can I get the token?

Comment: I can see no reason not to do everything in one form. Why would you need a second form?

Comment: It is one form and I jsut modifing the username

Answer (score 0):

you need to get that token and clone it to your new form.
something like:

```
var token = $('#realToken').clone();
token.prop('id', 'newTokenId'); // assign a new id. to prevent repeated id
$('#fakeHtmlForm').append(token);
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I get the token? The user needs to add our html file to his favorites and clicks on it every time he wants to login.